# Select specific text in UITextView to fire a segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I’m trying to add a function to my application where the user can select a PRESPECIFIED text by me in order to fire a segue and get an explanation/information about what the user has selected.

The following text is an example:

Hawaii is the most recent of the 50 *"U.S. states"* and joined the Union on August 21, 1959.

The user can select "U.S. states" and will get information about U.S. states.

So Can I do that with Xcode or do I have to work with some html editing application? and if so, where would be a good place (online or book) to start learning how to do such a thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There may be better ways, but I know of one way to do what you're asking.

1. Create a NSMutableAttributedString with the text you want shown
2. Determine the range of characters you want to be clickable and using setAttributes:rangeSet, add the NSLinkAttributeName attribute with a value of a string you can use to identify the clicked region.
3. Create a UITextView and set the attributedString property to the string from above
4. Set some object as the delegate of your UITextView
5. Override the textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange: method. Return NO here, but do what you want with the URL, created from the string you used before.

Here's the code part. I'll leave the UITextView creation to you.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attString = self.textView.attributedText.mutableCopy;
    [attString setAttributes:@{NSLinkAttributeName:@"123"} range:NSMakeRange(0, 10)];
    self.textView.attributedText = attString;
    self.textView.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
    NSLog(@"%@", URL);
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: It worked but one of the main issue now is the clickable text's font and style are changing!

Comment: Yeah that's the default appearance for clickable text. Just add more attributes and you can style it however you'd like. Here's a list of options! https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html

Comment: thanks a lot. Now after I have experiencing it for the past couple of days I'm stuck at a different thing. When I'm adding anther NSMakeRange I couldn't figure out how to call a different segue for each NSMakerange (if I have more than one word obviously I want different explanation for each one and hence I would need to use a different segue). Do you have any background how to do that?

Comment: Awesome, glad you are figuring it out. I'm sure you noticed you get passed the URL for the section you just selected and you are able to configure your linked sections with whatever URL you want. Were there any other unanswered questions or is this solution going to work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Xcode. You will want to create a segue in the storyboard and add an identifier to the segue. Then in one of the `UITextViewDelegate` methods, you can check the text in the text view. If it matches, you can call the segue programmatically using `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`. Alternatively, you can create the entire segue programmatically using `-segueWithIdentifier:source:destination:performHandler:`.